# httprouter and negroni for public and private routing middleware

Tags: go, negroni

I'm having a difficult time understanding how to use negroni and httprouter together.

I have a couple of public routes, such as `/api/v1/ping`

I have a bunch of private routes that need auth middleware, such as `/api/v1/user`

If I want negroni Common middleware for all of my routes, but I want to apply the auth middleware and others to only the private routes, how can I set this up?

```
v1.router := httprouter.New()
v1.router.GET("/api/v1/ping", v1.ping)
v1.router.GET("/api/v1/user", v1.getUsers)

n := negroni.Classic()
n.UseHandler(v1.router)

http.ListenAndServe(port, n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and adapt the technique described in "[Path Prefix Middleware in Go](https://www.calhoun.io/path-prefix-middleware/) ", which is using [`net/http/#ServeMux`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux), with another router ([`gorilla/mux`](https://github.com/gorilla/mux)), but should be valid for [`julienschmidt/httprouter`](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) as well:

> ### Specifying middleware based on route prefixes
>
> This is where the magic happens, and it is also where things get confusing.
>
> The easiesy way I have found to specify middleware for a path prefix is to setup a second muxer (we use the `sirMuxalot` variable for ours below) that has the path prefixes we want to apply middleware to, and to then pass in our original router wrapped in some middleware for those routes.
>
> This works because the `sirMuxalot` router won’t ever call the middleware-wrapped router unless the path prefix we define gets matched with the incoming web request’s path.
>
> ```
> sirMuxalot := http.NewServeMux()
> sirMuxalot.Handle("/", r)
> sirMuxalot.Handle("/api/", negroni.New(
>     negroni.HandlerFunc(APIMiddleware),
>     negroni.Wrap(r),
> ))
> sirMuxalot.Handle("/dashboard/", negroni.New(
>     negroni.HandlerFunc(DashboardMiddleware),
>     negroni.Wrap(r),
> ))
>
> n := negroni.Classic()
> n.UseHandler(sirMuxalot)
> http.ListenAndServe(":3000", n)
> ```